# jQuery dropdown (selectbox) only show list below

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

I use this jQuery plugin: http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/selectyze

I noticed that the dropdown-list only expand below the selectbox witch make the list go "outside" browser-window when open a list in the bottom at the page. Witch you probably know the standard selectbox expad above the selectbox if there is to little space below, it this possible to at to this script in some way?

**Plugin script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // simple Selectyze call
    $(".selectyze").Selectyze();
    // call with options
    $(".selectyze").Selectyze({
        theme:'css3',
        effectOpen:'fade',
        effectClose:'slide'
    });
});
```

**jQuery**

```
/************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
@Name :         Selectyze - jQuery Plugin
@Revison :      1.1
@Date :         25/01/2011
@Author:        Mickael SURREL - ALPIXEL Agency - (www.myjqueryplugins.com - www.alpixel.fr) 
@License :      Open Source - MIT License : http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

**************************************************************************
*************************************************************************/
(function($) {
$.fn.Selectyze = function(opt) {
    var defaults = {
        theme:'css3',
        effectOpen : 'slide',
        effectClose : 'slide'
    }; 

    if(this.length)
    return this.each(function() {

        /** vars **/
        var 
            opts = $.extend(defaults, opt),
            $this = $(this),
            optionselected = $this.find('option').filter(':selected'),
            DivSelect = $('<div>', {'class' : 'DivSelectyze '+opts.theme+''}),
            UlSelect = $('<ul>',{'class':'UlSelectize'}),
            liHtml = '';

        zIndex = 9999;

        /** DOM construction && manipulation **/
        constructList($this);
        $this.hide();
        $this.after(DivSelect);
        DivSelect.html('<a href="#" rel="'+optionselected.val()+'" class="selectyzeValue">'+optionselected.text()+'</a>');

        UlSelect.appendTo(DivSelect).html(liHtml);
        $('.DivSelectyze').each(function(i,el){
            $(this).css('z-index',zIndex);
            zIndex -= 10;
        });

        /** Actions **/
        n=false;
        DivSelect.mouseenter(function() {n =false;}).mouseleave(function() {n = true;});

        DivSelect.find('a.selectyzeValue').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            closeList($('ul.UlSelectize').not($(this).next()));
            openList($(this).next('ul.UlSelectize'));
        });

        UlSelect.find('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            DivSelect.find('a.selectyzeValue').text($(this).text());
            $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));           
            $this.trigger('change');         
            closeList($this.next().find('.UlSelectize'));
        });

        $(document).click(function(e){if(n) closeList($('.UlSelectize').not(':hidden'));});

        /** Construct HTML list ul/li **/
        function constructList(el){
            /** Creat list content **/
            if(el.has('optgroup').length)
            {
                el.find('optgroup').each(function(i,el){
                    liHtml += '<li><span class="optgroupTitle">'+$(this).attr('label')+'</span><ul>';
                    $(this).children().each(function(i,el){
                        liHtml += '<li><a rel="'+$(this).val()+'" href="#">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>';
                    });
                    liHtml += '</ul></li>';
                });
            }
            else
            {
                el.find('option').each(function(i,el){
                    liHtml += '<li><a rel="'+$(this).val()+'" href="#">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>';
                });
            }
        }

        /** Effect Open list **/
        function openList(el) {
            switch (opts.effectOpen) {
                case 'slide' :
                    if(!el.is(':hidden')) el.stop(true,true).slideUp('fast');   
                    else el.stop(true,true).slideDown('fast');  
                break;
                case 'fade':
                    if(!el.is(':hidden')) el.stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');   
                    else el.stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); 
                break;
                default :
                    if(!el.is(':hidden')) el.stop(true,true).hide();    
                    else el.stop(true,true).show(); 
            }
        }

        /** Effect Close list **/
        function closeList(el) {
            switch (opts.effectClose) {
                case 'slide' :
                    el.stop(true,true).slideUp('fast');
                break;
                case 'fade':
                    el.stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');
                break;
                default :
                    el.hide();  
            }
        }

    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
/************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
@Name :         Selectyze - jQuery Plugin CSS
@Revison :      1.0
@Date :         19/12/2011
@Author:        Mickael SURREL - ALPIXEL Agency - (www.myjqueryplugins.com - www.alpixel.fr) 
@License :       Open Source - MIT License : http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

**************************************************************************
*************************************************************************/

/***************************/
/** Common to every theme **/
/***************************/
.DivSelectyze {
    position:relative;
    width:253px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.DivSelectyze .selectyzeValue {
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.DivSelectyze ul {list-style:none;}
.DivSelectyze .UlSelectize {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    display:none;
}

.DivSelectyze li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.optgroupTitle {
    display:block;
}
/*******************************/
/** END COMMON TO EVERY THEME **/
/*******************************/
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/




/*----------------------------------
 You can add your own theme below !!
 To add your theme, be sure to have 5 CSS elements :

 .your_theme .selectyzeValue {}         -> Appearance of your select element
 .your_theme .UlSelectize {}            -> Appearance of the dropdown list
 .your_theme li a {}                    -> Appearance of the items into the dropdown list
 .your_theme li a:hover {}              -> items on hover
 .your_theme .optgroupTitle {}          -> Appearance of the optgroup label !! only if you have <optgroup> element into your list 


 that's all ! \o/
----------------------------------*/



    /*****************/
    /** SKYPE THEME **/
    /*****************/
    .skype .selectyzeValue {
        font:18px/45px Arial;
        color:#2a98c1;
        width:254px;
        height:45px;
        background:url('bg_skype.png') no-repeat;
        padding-left:15px
    }

    .skype .UlSelectize {
        top:39px;
        left:6px;
        width:239px;
        border:1px solid #00aff0;
        background-color:#f7f8ff
    }

    .skype li a {
        height:28px;
        font:14px/30px Arial;
        background-color:transparent;
        color:#2a98c1;
        border-top:1px solid #84d8f8;
        padding-left:10px
    }

    .skype li a:hover {
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#2a98c1;/** gradient bgcolors */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#84d8f8), to(#0ab2f1)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #84d8f8, #0ab2f1); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
        background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #84d8f8, #0ab2f1); /* FF3.6 */
        background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #84d8f8, #0ab2f1); /* IE10 */
        background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #84d8f8, #0ab2f1); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #84d8f8, #0ab2f1)
    }

    .skype .optgroupTitle {
        margin-top:15px;
        font-size:16px;
        padding-left:10px;
        background-color:#0fb1ef;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/4dgJw/7 now its 100% working and downvoters please add comment!

Comment: well check the above link it is 100% working!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how this plugin works.
But I use this cutomizable is object-oriented.
http://des.delestesoft.com:8080/?go=7